# Delete commits but not the last one in git

Tags: git

I have a long messy git commit history. I would like to delete all commits between the head and head@{119}. I've tried rebase, but since a lot of the commits were little changes to the same few lines, I would be making probably 200 corrections. If squashing them is the proper route, then how can I make git automatically respect the most recent change? It's asking for me to fix conflicts, but shouldn't it be obvious that my most recent commit is the change I'd like to keep? How can I make git do that? And if squashing isn't the right route, can I just delete the commits between head and head@{119} (not including the commit the head is on now).

I'm not very good with Git, and I've researched quite a bit on Google and here on SO, but I'm not experienced enough with it to figure out how to apply those answers to my question. There are a few questions that are similar, but if someone could be a little more clear as to the application here it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I answered assuming you meant `HEAD~119` rather than `HEAD@{119}`.

Comment: careful there. HEAD@{119} is VEEEEEERRRY different from HEAD~119. I would normally assume the question is related to HEAD~119.

Comment: I was talking about HEAD@{119}, although I don't really understand the difference. I suppose that's another question, but when I run git reflog, it's the 119th commit back. I also know the commit hash, so I can just use that to avoid the confusion, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the answer by Ry-](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59597040/1256452) for a practical method of doing this.

Note that what you are really doing is discarding all commits *including* that last one, *after* making a *new* commit that is just as good as the last one—except that it's *better* than the last one, as its parent is the 119th-to-last.  That is, we're telling our Git to stop using some set of existing commits, and start using some set of new-and-improved commits.  In this case there's just one new-and-improved commit, which replaces a lot of old-and-lousy ones.

Pictorially, we can draw each commit as a node in a graph (because it is).  The actual name of each Git commit is some big ugly hash ID.  We can use single uppercase letters to stand in for these big ugly hash IDs, although we'll run out long before we hit 120 commits, which is of course one reason Git uses big ugly hash IDs and not simple one-letter IDs.  But *in principle* this drawing captures the important reality.  A *branch name* like `master` contains the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain:

```
       ...  <-H   <--master
```

We say that `master` *points to* the last commit (which in this case is `H`, implying that maybe there are only eight commits in this repository).  Commit `H` itself contains the hash ID of its immediate predecessor `G`:

```
    ... <-G <-H   <--master
```

so `H` *points to* `G`, but `G` points back to another earlier commit too:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

This goes on until we reach the very first commit (at which point I lazily stop drawing the in-between arrows as arrows):

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Each commit holds some *data:* a full snapshot of all of your source files.  And, each commit also holds some *metadata:* who made it, when, why (a log message) and so on.  The *parent commit hash ID* is part of the metadata.

Now, suppose we make a *copy* of `H` that is exact *except* that instead of naming `G` as its parent, it names commit `C` as its parent?  That is, we make this:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master
       \
        H'
```

where `H'` is this copy of `H`—a ninth commit.  We'll need a *name* to keep track of this last commit ... but let's use `master`, by forcing Git to make the name `master` point to `H'` instead of `H`:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   [abandoned]
       \
        H'  <-- master
```

The way Git *finds* commits is to take a branch name, like `master`, and use its arrow—its (single) stored commit hash ID—to find the *last* commit.  From that commit, Git follows the internally-stored arrow backwards to the commit's parent, and so on.

By ripping `master` away from commit `H` and making it point to commit `H'` instead, we make it impossible to *find* commit `H`.  When you start from `master` and list commits, you see `H'`, then `C`, then `B`, then `A`.  If you don't pay attention to the commit hash IDs—`H'`'s is different from `H`'s—you might think you're still seeing `H`, then `C`, as if `H` is still there.  But it's *not* there—not in *this* list, anyway.

Commit `H` *is* still in your repository, and if you know its hash ID, you can still see it—along with all the commits before it.  If you know the secret<sup>1</sup> methods of finding old abandoned commits during their grace period before they're really discarded, you can use that to find commit `H` too.  But if you start with your name `master` and look at commits, you won't see the original `H`.

**Be aware that any *other* clone of this repository may still retain the original commits.**  To get them to read the way *yours* does, you must:

1. deliver to them the new-and-improved commit `H'` (this part is easy: any `git push` or `git fetch` can do this); *and*
2. *force* them to move *their* `master`, and/or any other name by which they find commit `H`, so that they find `H'` instead.

Step 2 is, or can be, harder: if they don't *want* to change, they won't.  If you have the right authority, you can use `git push --force` or `git push --force-with-lease` to *make* them do it.  If not, you can't.

Once you get *all* clones of this repository to discard the originals,<sup>2</sup> everyone now has this set of commits.  History now looks like:

```
A--B--C--H'  <-- master
```

because history, in a Git repository, *is* the set of commits in the repository.  You view it by having Git start at some specific commit—such as the one to which a branch name like `master` points—and work backwards.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Not actually secret.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

<sup>2</sup>As with your own clone, they *may* hang on to the original commit for some time, especially if they have their own reflogs.  A `--bare` server-side repository, such as those at GitHub or other hosting services, usually does *not* have reflogs, so stale commits that have been hidden away tend to vanish from those more quickly.  It's still never *instant* though.  The GitHub folks say that it may take a day or two, for instance.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer torek! It really helped me understand what I was actually aiming to do (which wasn't what I thought I wanted to do). I marked your answer as correct since it gives such an in-depth explanation of the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Point the branch at the last commit that should stay as-is, preserving the difference as staged changes:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~119
```

Commit the difference as a new commit:

```
git commit
```

If the most recent commit is also the commit message you’d like to use for this:

```
git commit --reuse-message=HEAD@{1}
```